# Consulta Ejercicio Arrays y Diccionarios JS

Tags: javascript, diccionarios

Estoy realizando un curso de introducción a la programación, usamos JavaScript y la consola de el navegador para el mismo, vimos tipos de datos,operaciones,variables y su comparación, estructuras de selección e iteracion, arrays, el tema es que me he quedado estancado cuando empezó a sumarse el tema de los diccionarios y el uso junto con los arrays, es un tema que no entiendo nada, me pusieron un ejercicio practico para el que tengo acceso a la solución, pero no quiero seguir para adelante sin haber entendido la solución

> El ejercicio es :
>
> 1. Programa un ejemplo que almacene en un array todas las cartas de la baraja, cada una representada con un diccionario que tenga un palo y
>    un valor.
> 2. Partiendo del array que has construido en el ejercicio anterior, construye un algoritmo que filtre en un nuevo array sólo las cartas
>    rojas, y en otro array las cartas negras.
> 3. Partiendo del array que has construido en el ejercicio anterior, construye un algoritmo que filtre en un nuevo array las cartas rojas y
>    pares. Luego imprime en la consola la última carta de ese nuevo array.

Y la solucion es :

```
var baraja = [];
var palos = ["c", "p", "t", "d"];
for (var i = 0; i < palos.length; i = i + 1) {
 for (var j = 1; j <= 12; j = j + 1) {
 baraja[baraja.length] = { p: palos[ i ], v: j };
 }
}
var rojas = [];
var negras = [];
for (var i = 0; i < baraja.length; i = i + 1) {
 if (baraja[ i ].palo === "c" || baraja[ i ].palo === "d") {
 rojas[rojas.length] = baraja[ i ];
 } else {
 if (baraja[ i ].palo === "p" || baraja[ i ].palo === "t") {
 negras[negras.length] = baraja[ i ];
 }
 }
}
var rojaspares = [];
for (var i = 0; i < rojas.length; i = i + 1) {
 if (rojas[ i ].valor % 2 === 0) {
 rojaspares[rojaspares.length] = rojas[ i ];
 }
}
var ultimacarta = { palo: rojaspares[rojaspares.length - 1].palo,
 valor: rojaspares[rojaspares.length - 1].valor };
console.log(ultimacarta);
```

Si alguien me puede desarrollar y explicar la solución, o decirme su explicación, lógica o razonamiento, me gustaría lograr comprenderla y poder seguir adelante, gracias

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no entiendes? Si tenemos que explicarte todo el código significaría que no sabes nada de javascript y por tanto deberías leer algo primero sobre la sintaxis (la pregunta sería demasiado amplia)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero declaras una variable de nombre **baraja** y le asignas el valor de un **arreglo vació**.

```
var baraja = [];
```

Después una variable de nombre **palos** y se le asigna un arreglo con 4 elementos ("corazones","palos","trébol","diamantes").

```
var palos = ["c", "p", "t", "d"];
```

Lo siguiente que se realiza es un **for** el cual se compone de lo siguiente:

una variable de nombre **i** con un valor inicial de **0**, seguido de un parámetro en dónde indicamos cuándo se detendrá la iteración (palos.length) y por último incrementamos en uno el valor de i por cada vez que se recorre el **for**.

Dentro del primer **for**, existe otra iteración, ahora con la variable incremental **j** y de valor inicial **1**, definimos un tope estático de **12 ciclos** (Número de cartas por cada forma) e incrementamos en uno nuevamente.

```
for (var i = 0; i < palos.length; i = i + 1) {
 for (var j = 1; j <= 12; j = j + 1) {
 baraja[baraja.length] = { p: palos[ i ], v: j };
 }
}
```

En total son **48** ciclos y asignamos ese valor a **baraja**.

Ahora declaramos dos nuevas variables (rojas y negras) asignándoles arreglos 
vacíos.

```
var rojas = [];
var negras = [];
```

Nuevamente un **for** con la variable **i** en **0**, con el limite de **48** de **baraja** obtenido del ejercicio anterior. Dentro de esta iteración incluimos una condicional con **if** en dónde separaremos rojas y negras:

Sí la carta es igual a **c** `baraja[ i ].palo === "c"`
o si la carta es igual a **d** `baraja[ i ].palo === "d"`
se las asignaremos a **rojas**

> Recuerda en un **if** esto: **||** es equivalente a un **OR**

En cambio si la carta contiene **p** o **t** se asignaran las cartas a negras.

```
for (var i = 0; i < baraja.length; i = i + 1) {
 if (baraja[ i ].palo === "c" || baraja[ i ].palo === "d") {
 rojas[rojas.length] = baraja[ i ];
 } else {
 if (baraja[ i ].palo === "p" || baraja[ i ].palo === "t") {
 negras[negras.length] = baraja[ i ];
 }
 }
}
```

Declaramos una variable de nombre **rojaspares** y le asignamos un arreglo vació.

```
var rojaspares = [];
```

Una iteración final con una condición para identificar de las cartas rojas los pares.

```
for (var i = 0; i < rojas.length; i = i + 1) {
 if (rojas[ i ].valor % 2 === 0) {
 rojaspares[rojaspares.length] = rojas[ i ];
 }
}
```

Se declara una última variable **ultimacarta** asignándole un objeto con dos valores (tipo y número).

```
var ultimacarta = { 
    palo: rojaspares[rojaspares.length - 1].palo,
    valor: rojaspares[rojaspares.length - 1].valor 
 };
```

Mostramos en consola el resultado.

```
console.log(ultimacarta);
```

Comment: Revisa esta liga para comprender la parte en dónde obtienes los pares: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Aritm%C3%A9ticos#.25_.28modular.29